# Continuous delivery or continuous integration workflow with Packer and Vagrant

Tags: windows, continuous-integration, vagrant, packer, continuous-delivery

I am C#/Asp.Net Windows developer and I am interested in the applicability of Continuous Delivery in .Net/Windows world.

Currently what confuses me is the way we should actually work with Packer and Vagrant.

Here is what I understand about CD and packer:

1. Packer can be used to take your base .iso and build an output image (appliance) using set of provisioners.

   As per my understanding this image should be treated as an image of environment with already deployed infrastructure (IIS, SqlServer) matching as much as possible the production environment + already deployed web site you deliver to your customer.
2. As per Continuous Delivery approach you should aim getting feedback about your code/configuration as fast as possible.

   As you should run your smoke+functional+non-functional tests on environment close to production you should use this image as their target.
   It means that you will get the results of functional tests after you build your image, deploy the infrastructure, deploy the website.
   The appliance is not treated as valid and ready for use until it passes all tests.
   But it contradicts with fast feedback rule - tests are run late in the pipeline, because in fact the depend on the built image and it takes long to build it.
3. When you deliver you can take your provisioners and run them from scratch on genuine hardware instead of Packer or you can somehow use the image itself (run as virtual server)

So I see that the workflow can be the following:

1. A developer checks out the source code from mainline.
2. Vagrant file is located under the source control. It contains the name of base image (located on file share for example) + the set of provisioners.
3. The developer builds the code using `msbuild`.
4. Then he runs unit tests as usual.
5. Then he runs the website. For the first time he need to run `vagrant up` and the image gets built (it takes long). The OS is installed, infrastructure is configured, then the website is deployed. After that he gets the local copy of production-like environment with deployed website built from the current code.
6. Not clear how does he debug his code...
7. If needed he runs some/all functional/non-functional tests.

Two more steps:

8. After he makes a local change/takes the latest code from SCM he runs the whole cycle again (but probably provision scripts will notice that some of them should not be applied)!
9. When he needs to make configuration change he changes provision scripts and rerun the whole cycle as well.

The build server works similar but it uses packer to build the result image and probably vagrant to bring the image to live for testing.

I see that potentially the workflow can be optimized (cached at some points). You can skip running the step unless any of dependencies change:

```
Base image (.iso) -------------------------\
                                            |---> Base OS ready for vagrant
OS provision scripts (packer-windows)  ----/



Base OS ready for vagrant  -------------------\
                                              |---> OS with IIS/Sql
Infrastructure provision scripts (IIS, Sql) --/



OS with IIS/Sql  --------------\
                                |--------> OS with deployed Website
Built website package   -------/    /
                                   /
Deployment scripts ---------------/



Web site source code ------\
                            |----> Built website package
Unit tests   --------------/



OS with deployed Website -------------\
                                       |----> Ready and tested compliance
Functional/non-functional tests   ----/
```

Can anybody share/recommend the efficient workflow to use Packer and Vagrant?

Comment: You can debug using the Visual Studio Remote debugger - install it on your vagrant/packer boxes and then attach to process from your VS instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly whats your question - I am from linux/java world and do apply the same workflow, it works fine.

1. I have a packer template that build centos image with no customization (it creates the OS, adds our custom user ...)
2. I have puppet provisioning script that will create the VMs (I use 2 VMs) and will install oracle/gradle/oracle/apache/weblogic...
   This step is done once when the VM needs to be initialized

   ```
   app.vm.provision "shell", path: "puppet/script/install-puppet-modules-app.sh"
   app.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
     puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
     puppet.manifest_file = "base-app.pp"
     puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
     puppet.hiera_config_path = "puppet/hiera.yaml"
     #puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
   end
   ```
3. I have deployment script that are run every time I boot the VM

   ```
   app.vm.provision "shell", path: "puppet/script/run-app.sh", privileged: false, run: 'always'
   ```

The key is **`run: 'always'`** so you make sure this step is run each time you run `vagrant up`

I run functional test (using selenium) from another VM (I have a hub machine and windows client machine with browser installed) so I fire those ones only when I am ready to run the tests

The constraints I have:

- I need to run `vagrant up` specifying which machines needs to be boot, as I run 2 VMs for the app server (app+db) and 2 other VMs for the testing (selenium hub+windows). I you have only 1 VM for the app server you can use the `primary` option and it avoids to wait and take resources you don't use
- I would like to take advantage of the [vagrant snapshot](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/snapshot.html) feature, however I face an [issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6752). If I take a snapshot I need to run all or none of the provisioners which breaks my flow as I am using initial provisioner and provisioner to run always

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Comment: Some questions: 1. How (or what) do you deploy to production? Do you use vagrant again or do you run packer to build the end-product image of OS with your website deployed as part of the same puppet provision scripts you used in vagrant? 2. How fast things happen (packer build, vagrant up) in minutes? 3. What do you do when you change you base image config (new user for example)? 4. Is packer/vagrant a part of your continuous integration workflow?

Comment: 1. Production is run on AWS, I don't (and do not recommend to) use vagrant in Production, its good tool for dev/test but there are limitations (security, log analysis ...) when coming to production. we setup the instance using the same puppet/shell script that we use on vagrant to setup the production instance but I am looking to leverage AWS specific solution (like cloud formation).

Comment: 2. Its more a magnitude of hour. packer build all together takes 1 hour (windows instance are pretty long to create because of windows update); vagrant initial provision takes again 1 hour (we also import a 50 GB DB in oracle but in parallel of other script). Further deployment are pretty fast and happens in minutes

Comment: 3. we did not have the case yet but if we need, we would rerun packer to create the base box and distribute to other. dev would need to rerun the vagrant initial provisioner and take it from there. Its a bit long but can be done at night

Comment: 4. we use vagrant for dev and for functional testing (selenium) so we did not integrate that to our CI, we run the functional testing once at the end of a sprint. I know there are some jenkins plugin that exists, I did not try but if it worked we could integrate it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Good to learn some real-world experience